# What is the average salary of Assistant Professor in South Korea?

Tags: career-path, professorship, salary, assistant-professor

What is the average salary of Assistant Professor in South Korea? How tough it is for a foreign faculty member to get public and private sector funded projects for his/her lab?

Answer (score 1):

Quite good: $43-50k

Since foreign faculty members are common in South Korea, likely it isn't any tougher than for local faculty.

source: https://www.chronicle.com/article/South-Korea-Brings-in-Foreign/126508

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by **"_Quite good_"**?  That sounds like a fairly modest salary by US standards; is it higher by South Korean standards?

Comment: @Nat Why on Earth would you apply US standards to a Korean salary? The americentrism on this website is crazy. If amara says "quite good" for a Korean salary, there is no reason to assume that it means anything but "quite good for Korean standards".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Seems silly to assume stuff when it's so easy to just ask.  Ideally, I was hoping for more than just, say, "_It's good by Korean salaries_", but rather some more explicit qualification, e.g., "_It's competitive with other positions a Korean PhD might pursue._".